# AddSnapShotListener is repeating the document reading in one instance

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I am using addSnapshotListener for realtime updates, the documents are repeated which should not be the case, but when using `getDocuments()` the documents are repeated once only, I need to use `addSnaphotListener` but not want to duplicate the document reading, please assist where I am wrong in using snapshot listener.

I am using Firestore database in Swift iOS. Below is the code I am using

Code with `addSnapShotListener()`:

```
func getComments() {

      //print(postId + "received")
        let commentsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments")

        commentsRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                      // self.length = snapshot.count


                        let data = document.data()
                        let username = data["comment_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let comment = data["comment_author_comment"] as? String ?? ""
                        let spinnerC = data["comment_author_spinnerC"] as? String ?? ""
                        let fullname = data["comment_author_fullname"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["comment_author_email"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentUserImageUrl = data["comment_user_image"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentuser_id = data["comment_author_id"] as? String ??  ""
                        self.checkl1value = data["l1"] as? Bool


                        let newComment = Comment(_documentId: document.documentID, _commentAuthorUsername: username, _commentAuthorFullName: fullname, _commentAuthorComment: comment, _commentUserImage: commentUserImageUrl, _commentAuthorSpinnerC: spinnerC, _commentAuthorId:commentuser_id, _checkl1value: self.checkl1value)

                        self.comments.append(newComment)
                    //   print(self.length!)

                    }
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code With `getDocuments()`:

```
func getComments() {

      //print(postId + "received")
        let commentsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments")

        commentsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            } else {

                if let snapshot = snapshot {

                    for document in snapshot.documents {

                      // self.length = snapshot.count


                        let data = document.data()
                        let username = data["comment_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let comment = data["comment_author_comment"] as? String ?? ""
                        let spinnerC = data["comment_author_spinnerC"] as? String ?? ""
                        let fullname = data["comment_author_fullname"] as? String ?? ""
                        let email = data["comment_author_email"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentUserImageUrl = data["comment_user_image"] as? String ?? ""
                        let commentuser_id = data["comment_author_id"] as? String ??  ""
                        self.checkl1value = data["l1"] as? Bool


                        let newComment = Comment(_documentId: document.documentID, _commentAuthorUsername: username, _commentAuthorFullName: fullname, _commentAuthorComment: comment, _commentUserImage: commentUserImageUrl, _commentAuthorSpinnerC: spinnerC, _commentAuthorId:commentuser_id, _checkl1value: self.checkl1value)

                        self.comments.append(newComment)
                    //   print(self.length!)

                    }
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest to clear `comments` array when `snapshot` is available and then refill it would always keep a single copy of data without duplicating them. Currently you are appending items from snapshot to `comments` array which would add duplicate items as & when `commentsRef.getDocuments` is invoked when a change is detected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking to only handle the changes between the snapshots. To do that you'll want to loop over `instead of`, as shown in the documentation on [viewing changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
>     .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
>         guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
>             print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
>             return
>         }
>         snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
>             if (diff.type == .added) {
>                 print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
>             }
>             if (diff.type == .modified) {
>                 print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
>             }
>             if (diff.type == .removed) {
>                 print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Initially your listener will get called with `diff.type == .added` for each existing document, and then when there are changes it'll get called with the right mix of `type`s.